# Bootstrap Modal sobre Modal por JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Boa tarde,

Vi vários exemplos na internet de um modal abrindo sobre outro modal com o bootstrap, mas nenhum deles utilizando javascript. Não tem como abrir um modal sobre o outro com o bootstrap utilizando javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Eu passei pelo mesmo problema, você deve manter a informação de quantos modals estão abertos, caso um novo seja aberto ele deve ter um z-index maior do que o que já está, para sempre aparecer na frente, para isso os eventos shows e hidden do modal são tratados.
segue o exemplo do código:

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function( event ) {
            $(this).removeClass( 'fv-modal-stack' );
            $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals', $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals' ) - 1 );
            });


$( '.modal' ).on( 'shown.bs.modal', function ( event ) {

               // keep track of the number of open modals

               if ( typeof( $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals' ) ) == 'undefined' )
               {
                 $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals', 0 );
               }


               // if the z-index of this modal has been set, ignore.

            if ( $(this).hasClass( 'fv-modal-stack' ) )
                    {
                    return;
                    }

            $(this).addClass( 'fv-modal-stack' );

            $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals', $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals' ) + 1 );

            $(this).css('z-index', 1040 + (10 * $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals' )));

            $( '.modal-backdrop' ).not( '.fv-modal-stack' )
                    .css( 'z-index', 1039 + (10 * $('body').data( 'fv_open_modals' )));


            $( '.modal-backdrop' ).not( 'fv-modal-stack' )
                    .addClass( 'fv-modal-stack' ); 

             });


    });
```

Site com exemplo funcionando: http://miles-by-motorcycle.com/static/bootstrap-modal/index.html

Comment: seria interessante tbm colocar o html aqui e se possivel em um pastebin, mas aqui principalmente, pois no link que passou nao se tem garantia que amanha podera ser visto o exemplo.

Comment: Essa modal poderia ter o recurso de ser arrastada? ou fica apenas fixa acima da outra?

Comment: Coloquei no pastebin para a comunidade: http://pastebin.com/tBDHES4y

Answer (score 2):

**Vamos direto a resposta**:

Usando `setTimeout`, pois o `.modal-backdrop` não é criado quando o evento `show.bs.modal` é acionado.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#abrir').click(function () {
        $('#myModal').modal({
            show: true
        })
    });
        $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function (event) {
            var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
            $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
            }, 0);
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Abrir</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">Alguma coisa aqui dentro.
              <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal2" class="btn btn-primary">Abrir</a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Fechar</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Outro botão a ser implementado</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 2</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">Alguma coisa aqui dentro.
              <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal3" class="btn btn-primary">Abrir</a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Fechar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal3">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 3</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">Acho que até aqui deu pra compreender...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Fechar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81050/abrir-m%C3%BAltiplas-modais-bootstrap/102695#102695)

Comment: Você poderia incluir o código na própria resposta? Vai que o jsfiddle cai ou some...

Comment: @bfavaretto está feito!

Answer (score 1):

Sim, tem como abrir um modal sobre outro utilizando JavaScript. Veja este exemplo:

http://www.bootply.com/86958

HTML:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div><div class="container"></div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Content for the dialog / modal goes here.
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal2" class="btn btn-primary">Launch modal</a>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="myModal2" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Second Modal title</h4>
        </div><div class="container"></div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Content for the dialog / modal goes here.
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#openBtn').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal({show:true})
});
```

Comment: Mas no caso, o segundo formulário não foi aberto por js né?

Comment: Mas cara, o segundo formulário não foi aberto por js. Foi aberto por causa da tag data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal2" que foi adicionada

Comment: Você pode utilizar a função JavaScript abaixo que lhe passei para abrir qualquer modal.

Comment: Não deu certo não! Sempre quando abro o modal ele fica sob o outro modal que já estava aberto!

Answer (score 1):

É possível usar sem javascript, basta colocar um botão dentro de um modal aberto pra chamar o outro modal.

Se quiser usar javascript para chamar o Modal, utilize o código seguinte:

```
$('.btn.chamar-modal-a').on('click',function(){
    $("#modalA").modal('show');
}
```

**OBS**: Presta atenção a sobreposição do Modal, no código, coloca o Modal A após Modal B, ou seja, Modal A em cima do Modal B.