# Abrir Múltiplas Modais Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Conforme documentação do bootstrap: [Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

> Múltiplas modais não são suportadas e requerem código adicional.

Estou tentando abrir várias modais dentro de outras, estas modais são chamadas de arquivos externos com `data-remote` e estou tendo um problema, elas ficam uma dentro das outras, parece redundante mas é como se o index delas ficasse no mesmo que a modal anterior.

Atualização da documentação sobre o metodo remoto:

**Original:**

> This option is deprecated since v3.3.0 and has been removed in v4. We
>   recommend instead using client-side templating or a data binding
>   framework, or calling jQuery.load yourself.
>
> If a remote URL is provided, content will be loaded one time via
>   jQuery's load method and injected into the .modal-content div. If
>   you're using the data-api, you may alternatively use the href
>   attribute to specify the remote source. An example of this is shown
>   below: `<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html"data-target="#modal">Click me</a>`

**Tradução:**

> Esta opção esta obsoleta desde v3.3.0 e sera removida na versão 4.
>   Nós recomendamos inves de utilizar  o remote usar client-side
>   templating ou data binding ou chamar o metodo load do jQuery.
>
> Se uma URL remota é fornecido, o conteúdo será carregado uma vez
>   através do método load do jQuery e injetado na div .modal-content. Se
>   você estiver usando data-api, poderá preferir usar o atributo href
>   para especificar a origem remota. Um exemplo disso é mostrado abaixo:
>   `<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>`

**Exemplo:**

Página 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title></title>
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" data-remote="pagina2.html" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Página 2:

```
<div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Open Modal 2</button>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>



<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-2" data-remote="pagina3.html" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

O resultado será algo como:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como poderia resolver este problema ?

Comment: Tem um plugin muito bom chamado [Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) para criar _alerts_, _confirms_ e _prompts_, em todos os meus projetos eu não deixo de usa-los pela praticidade. Ele implementa o [multi-modal](https://jsfiddle.net/xez34yge/) talvez dar uma olhada no código dele ajude.

Comment: Para que criar múltiplas modais se você pode concentrar tudo em uma única modal? Basta trocar o conteúdo, texto, formulário, etc. na hora de de carregá-la.

Comment: Estas modais são utilizadas em várias  partes do sistema,  desta forma eu utilizo data-remote para chamar cada  uma das telas, elas podem ser modais ou não, usar tudo em uma requer reescrita de código em várias partes do projeto coisa que eu quero ao maximo evitar

Comment: Vc só precisa dizer qual é o layout da modal que será carregada. Não precisa criar 500 modais pra isso.

Comment: Você tem um exemplo ?

Comment: as modais são todas iguais, vc tem os botões em baixo, um título no cabeçalho e o conteúdo no meio.

Comment: quando vc carrega a modal do boostrap, vc passa os parâmetros via ajax pelo jquery, no atributo data-xxxx-bolinha, ou data-yyyy-quadrado, esses parâmetros podem ser capturados e reestruturar seu modal.

Comment: dá uma olhada aqui tem uns exemplos: http://opensource.locaweb.com.br/locawebstyle/documentacao/componentes/modal/

Comment: Conforme exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/filadown/Lyp615jw/ no 3 modal aberto eu uso `data-remote` para fazer o load de uma página, e nessa página ela possui mais outra modal que deve abrir, mas quando ela abre em vez de ficar no indice normal ele se torna um indice da pagina aberta.

Comment: porque você não usa o jquery mesmo função dialog() com parametro modal=true https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Tudo bem ? Leia por favor a descrição da recompensa que ela responde a sua pergunta rsrs.

Comment: ah desculpe não tinha visto..rsrsr

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Pois eh no jqueryUI eu sou ninja em criar modais e funciona legal, porém mudei para o bootstrap e o único recurso que não consegui passar para o bootsrap foi ele, o pior e que se você for no jqueryui.com e baixar apenas com o básico(Dialog) vai ser js/css = 100KB

Comment: @Highlander atualizei a resposta, ficou na seção 2 do post, funcionando usando remote e href.

Comment: @petersonfortes Assim que possível estarei realizando os novos testes, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você deseja abandonar o **jQueryUI**.

Seguindo o funcionamento dele o carregamento é feito pelo 
método `open`,  e neste open é carregado a nova *url* utilizando o `load`.

**Como é no jQueryUI:**

**Exemplo HTML:**

```
 <!-- DECLARANDO DIV -->
 <div id="cliente">
```

**Exemplo JS:**

```
$('#cliente').dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   height: 550,
   width: 860,
   modal: true,
   title: 'Cliente',
   show: "blind",
   buttons: {
      'Sair': function () {
         $(this).dialog('close');
      }
   },
   position: {
      at: 'top'
   },
   open: function () {
      $(this).load('cliente.html'); // Aqui permitimos que seja carregado a página.
   }
});

// Chamando a dialog no click 
 $('#cliente').dialog("open");
```

**Agora reproduzindo esta estrutura no Bootstrap:**

**Exemplo HTML:**

```
 <!-- DECLARANDO DIV -->
 // Apenas acrescentamos a classe para dar o efeito do Bootstrap.
 <div id="cliente" class="modal fade">
```

**Exemplo JS:**

```
function loadModal(id,url){
    $('#' + id).on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).load(url);
    });
}
// Chamando a função:
loadModal('Cliente','cliente.html')

// Chamando a modal no click, você pode usar tanto js quanto html usando o href:
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Cliente</a>
```

E nas suas páginas deverá ser incluido todo conteúdo dentro da classe `modal-dialog`:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <h1> Algum conteúdo aqui.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">Pesquisar</a>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" data-remote="index3.html">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Dentro dessas páginas incluídas você poderá abrir quantas modais quiser usando a `função loadModal()`.

Apenas não se esqueça de declarar a *div* na página inicial.

Aguardo seu Feedback.

Comment: Sua solução foi a mais simples para resolver este problema,perfeito.

Answer (score 6):

Em vez de você criar vários modais, use somente o `data-target` chamando o conteúdo para dentro do seu modal `data-target="#id_objeto"` e passe os parâmetros ou comportamento via `data-qualquercoisa`:

```
<div id="id_objeto">Seu conteúdo</div>
```

## Você pode fazer o seu conteúdo dinâmico dessa maneira

## Ou pode fazer um modal dentro de modal dessa maneira

Comment: utilizei o seu modelo para criar um modal dentro do while. Porém ao abrir um modal, vi pelo f12 que ele cria um elemento { padding-right:17px} e a cada modal que abro ele vai somando os 17px; ... Analisei meus arquivos e não encontrei nenhum padding. Tem noção de oq esta criando este elemento?

Comment: esse problema que está ocorrendo provavelmente é por causa da referência do botão.

Comment: Fala cara.... foi o seu tutorial que segui... no caso vc fala de qual botão? Foi aquele bloco do Modal não é utilizado... oq esta trazendo os dados ´esta linha:                                     <a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $posts['id']?>" data-id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-content="<h2>Título de exemplo 1</h2><p>Conteúdo feito dentro do modal 1</p>" data-title="Este título é o atributo 1" data-target="#element" data-button="mudar texto do botão salvar" title="<?php echo $posts['titulo']; ?>" >

Comment: estou tratando este problema por este link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83128/multiplo-modal-bootstrap-js-php?lq=1

Comment: Ivan eu removi os botões, porém o problema persiste.

Comment: @IvanFerrer Você poderia reeditar a sua resposta para se encaixar melhor na pergunta, tive que reeditar a minha pergunta para incluir informações importantes   e colocar um exemplo funcional do problema.

Comment: @IvanFerrer desta forma todas as modais ficariam em uma página só, como seria se você chama-se a modal 1 de outra pagina e na modal 1 voce chamar a modal 2 que esta em outra pagina ?

Comment: As modais do bootstrap abrem também ao link de uma página externa:`<a href="sua-url.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">abrir modal</a>` estando na mesma página. É só passar a URL. É só embutir o conteúdo que será exibido dentro da div. não precisa ter marcação html, só o conteúdo.

Comment: Você também pode implementar dentro do bs.modal:  `var url = $(this).find('[data-url]').data('url');
                 if (url != undefined && url != '') {
                       var id = $(this).attr('id');
                      $('#'+id+' .modal-body').load(url);
                  }` e passar a url como atributo `data-url="sua-url.html"`

Comment: Atualizei a url do exemplo, "só mais um modalzinho" carregando uma url externa.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode tentar lidar com modais múltiplas trabalhando com o [backdrop](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28144/modal-dentro-de-modal) e o [Z-index](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74435/bootstrap-modal-sobre-modal-por-js) do Modal.

**Como?**

Usando `setTimeout`, pois o `.modal-backdrop` não é criado quando o evento `show.bs.modal` é acionado.

Acredito que [este código](http://jsfiddle.net/yzgmqtgw/) deve ajudar.

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305821/multiple-modals-overlay)

---

Agora, quanto o uso do `data-remote`, uma vez que um objeto Modal é instanciado, ele é ligado ao elemento alvo. Cada chamada subsequente não irá atualizar os valores nas opções do `remote`. De forma que **os atributos são diferentes para cada instância**, quando o Modal é alternado, o valor do `data-remote` **não está sendo atualizado**.

Além do fato anterior, o plugin responsável pelo Modal carrega o `data-remote` no construtor do objeto Modal, de forma que mesmo que uma alteração seja feita para as opções do `remote` ele nunca vai ser recarregado.

Uma gambiarra possível de ser implementada seria:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Ou você pode tentar dificultar as coisas e fazer algo como uma verificação do caminho da página que deve aparecer no modal, se é ou não diferente da anterior. Se for, destruir; se não for, então não há necessidade de recarregar.

```js
$('[data-load-remote]').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var remote = $this.data('load-remote');
    if(remote) {
        $($this.data('remote-target')).load(remote);
    }
});
```

```html
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/q89Lhmss/0/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">Página 1</a>
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/ng75mLnz/0/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">Página 2</a>
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/jvr0dj61/0/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">Página 3</a>
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/zsjq4u8z/0/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">Página 4</a>

<div class="modal hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal Principal</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Alguma coisa</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Fechar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Exemplo funcionando [AQUI](http://jsfiddle.net/ThLYb/454/).

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286332/twitter-bootstrap-remote-modal-shows-same-content-everytime)

Comment: É exatamente isto que eu quero evitar, estou usando jQueryUI dialog para fazer isto e vou sair dele para usar outro que faz o mesmo ? Interessante seria extender a função modal para suportar estas duas funções.

Comment: @Highlander atualizei a resposta, para tentar ajudar neste contexto também, qualquer dúvida é só perguntar.

Comment: +1 Testando sua solução

Comment: @Highlander funcionou como o esperado?

Comment: Não funcionou, este exemplo faz a mesma coisa que o meu exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/filadown/Lyp615jw/ você conseguiu pegar o meu código na pergunta e simular o problema ? cria a pag1 coloca o conteudo cria a pag2 coloca o conteudo, cria a pag 3 e tenta abrir elas na modal.

Comment: Quando você declara elas na mesma pagina tudo bem o problema é quando elas estão em outra página e são chamadas pelo data-remote que funciona como um load

Comment: @Highlander por favor, verifique se a atual resposta te ajuda no problema do data-remote, se eu ainda não entendi o problema um fiddle com o exemplo do erro encontrado talvez ajude .

Answer (score 2):

Segue exemplo de fazer essa coisa ai com jquery ui

```js
var $modal = $('<div>');
        $modal.css('line-height','1').html('teste1')
            .dialog({width :400,height: 250,modal: true,closeOnEscape: false,title:'Aviso',
                buttons: { Ok:function(){ $(this).remove(); } }
            }); 

var $modal = $('<div>');
        $modal.css('line-height','1').html('teste2')
            .dialog({width :400,height: 250,modal: true,closeOnEscape: false,title:'Aviso',
                buttons: { Ok:function(){ $(this).remove(); } }
            }); 
var $modal = $('<div>');
        $modal.css('line-height','1').html('teste3')
            .dialog({width :400,height: 250,modal: true,closeOnEscape: false,title:'Aviso',
                buttons: { Ok:function(){ $(this).remove(); } }
            }); 
var $modal = $('<div>');
        $modal.css('line-height','1').html('teste4')
            .dialog({width :400,height: 250,modal: true,closeOnEscape: false,title:'Aviso',
                buttons: { Ok:function(){ $(this).remove(); } }
            });
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

No Bootstrap os modais remotos são abertos em `modal-content` e o conteúdo remoto, ou modal remoto, tem as partes básicas como `header`, `body` e `footer`. Você deveria repetir pela lógica. A pergunta é `como é que você vai renderizar o segundo, terceiro, quarto... modais se no primeiro dado remoto o modal não carrega uma classe 'modal-content'`?

Explico!

Você tem na primeira página:

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" data-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/hwksuycy/20/show/" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    
    
    <!-- é essa classe que importa no Bootstrap 3.5 -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- o segundo modal será carregado aqui ou terá como alvo (target) esse elemento âncora, a CLASSE modal-content -->  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Veja o FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/n1odurrn/43/)

A classe `modal-content` é o que realmente importa aqui, como pode ser [**visto na documentação**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Agora, na página remota você tem o seguinte:

```html
<div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
   <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Open Modal 2</button>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>



<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-2" data-remote="pagina3.html" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Ou seja, você tem primariamente a estrutura do conteúdo de um modal, mas não tem a classe `modal-content` que seia a âncora do segundo modal, que carrega uma `modal-content`, mas que não tem uma como `parent`.

Bem, uma solução simples seria utilizar a ***[extensão Bootstrap Modal](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/)***.

Dê uma olhada na seção "**Stackable**".

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui fazer isso criando contêineres para cada modal, cada um com um z-index diferente, assim um modal conseguia sobrepor o outro.

```
<div id="modalContainer"><!-- seu primeiro modal aqui --></div>
<div id="subModalContainer"><!-- seu segundo modal aqui --></div>
```

E no CSS:

```
#modalContainer { z-index: 100; }
#subModalContaineer { z-index: 1000; }
```