# multiplo modal > Bootstrap/JS/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, modal

Utilizei este link como referencia para criação do meu Modal: [Abrir Múltiplas Modais Bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81050/como-usar-multiplas-modals-no-bootstrap/81095#81095).

Após abrir um modal e clicar fora da caixa modal, quando retornamos para pagina, é aberto um estilo automatico de padding-right:17px, e a cada modal aberto ele valor é somado com mais 17px, resultado, a pagina vai encolhendo para esquerda por conta dos padding.

Utilizei o f12 para verificar oq se passa, 1º print tirada na index, sem abrir modal:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2º print tirado com modal aberto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz uma varredura atrás de algum padding-right tanto na index, como na singles que é de onde vem os dados para o modal, não foi encontrado nenhum padding.

```
{var a=parseInt(this.$body.css("padding-right")||0,10);this.originalBodyPad=document.body.style.paddingRight||"",this.bodyIsOverflowing&&this.$body.css("padding-right",a+this.scrollbarWidth)},c.prototype.resetScrollbar=function(){this.$body.css("padding-right",this.originalBodyPad)}
```

Como podem ver na print, o elemento {} esta informando que vem do inline, oque seria isto?

Detalhe: Se eu clicar em um link dentro do Modal, ele não cria o padding. O padding ocorre somente quando eu clico fora do modal e ele o fecha.

Comment: Alguem saberia me explicar oque é este style element(o)?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se seria a melhor solução pro seu caso, mas você poderia adicionar esse atributo no seu modal:

```
data-backdrop="static"
```

Ele desabilita o close do modal quando é clicado fora de sua área.

Comment: Hoje pude testar em um monitor dell de 17" e vi que o problema não ocorreu... ja onde eu estou desenvolvendo é um laptop com tela de 14" . Não sei por onde começar a procurar o problema...

Comment: Realmente, aqui não consegui reproduzir o problema... Estou usando um monitor de 17''.