# Como posso estar fazendo vários modais numa página, só puxando outra página PHP dentro do modal?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap

Tenho um código que abre um modal com uma outra página PHP dentro do modal, mas somente consegui fazer isso com uma página. Eu gostaria de fazer a mesma coisa usando esse código para os outros botões, só que abrindo outras páginas distintas. Alguém pode me ajudar com isso.

Meu código segue abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<style>

    .modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        padding-top: 20px; /* Location of the box */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        padding-left: 300px;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }

    /* Modal Content */
    .modal-content {
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0;
        width: 80%;
        background-image: url("images/fundo_claro.jpg") ;

        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px #000;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px #000;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    /* Add Animation */
    @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
        from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
        to {top:0; opacity:1}
    }

    @keyframes animatetop {
        from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
        to {top:0; opacity:1}
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
        background: #606061;
        color: #009dd9;
        line-height: 25px;
        position: relative;
        right: -12px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 660px;
        top: 23px;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 24px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-border-radius: 12px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;}

    .close:hover {
        background: #00d9ff;
    }
    .modal-header {
        padding: 2px 16px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);

    }

    .modal-body {
        padding: 2px 16px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        position: relative;
        }

    .modal-footer {

        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 20px 0;

    }
    .btn {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        vertical-align: middle;
        -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
        touch-action: manipulation;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        background-image: none;
        border: 1px solid ;
        border-radius: 4px;
        height: 50px ;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: white;
    }   
</style>
</head>
<body>

<center>
<button id="myBtn" style="cursor: pointer" >Grafico Failure Overall</button><br><br>
<button id="myBtn1"  style="cursor: pointer">Grafico Process Breakdown</button><br><br>
<button id="myBtn2" style="cursor: pointer" >Grafico Commodity Breakdown</button><br><br>
<button id="myBtn3" style="cursor: pointer" >Grafico Workmanship Breakdown</button><br><br>
<button id="myBtn4" style="cursor: pointer" >Grafico Reseat Breakdown</button><br><br>
<button id="myBtn5" style="cursor: pointer" >Grafico Desktop TBG</button><br><br>
<button id="myBtn6" style="cursor: pointer" >Grafico Notebook TBG</button><br><br>
<button id="myBtn7" style="cursor: pointer" >Grafico Ultrabook TBG</button>
</center>


<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <!-- <div class="modal-content"> -->

        <div class="modal-body">
        <span class="close">X</span><br>
            <?php include "grafico1.php";?>
        </div> 
</div>



<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Da uma olhadinha nessa pergunta é bem provável que um das respostas possa te ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81050/abrir-m%C3%BAltiplas-modais-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Opa, tranquilo?

Seguinte, do jeito que o código está apresentado você está inserindo o código do grafico1.php neste modal, porem o php é interpretado quando a página é carregada.

Tem algumas soluções para tal finalidade.

1. Seguindo sua linha pode criar vários modais com load de todos os arquivos php que você quer de uma vez, e em seguida esconder e exibir o que você desejar.
2. Você pode carregar por ajax o conteudo do php como por exemplo:

> jQuery.ajax({
>   url: "grafico1.php",
>   type: "POST",
>   success:function(data){
>       $('#modal').html(data); 
>   }});

3. Ou iframe que é outra possibilidade mas não recomendo.

E use o JQuery, é importante usar ele, alem de facilitar ele tem compatibilidade e suporte com vários browsers